# React Router Dom v6 HashRouter basename not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i want to use that Hashrouter, but when i try, i got this error:

```
<Router basename="/admin"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything.
```

i put "Homepage": "./admin" in packedjson

but when i use BrowserRouter, its render normaly, can anyone explain why, please?

The code i'm using to try to understand router v6:

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  Link,
  HashRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoutes = () => <Outlet />;

const Configuration = () => <h1>Configuration</h1>;
const SummaryPage = () => <h1>SummaryPage</h1>;
const Dashboard = () => <h1>Dashboard</h1>;
const Appointments = () => <h1>Appointments</h1>;
const NotFound = () => <h1>NotFound</h1>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter basename="/admin">
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <Link to="/dashboard" className="link">
          Home
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/configuration/configure" element={<Configuration />} />
        <Route path="/configuration" element={<SummaryPage />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/appointments" element={<Appointments />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/configuration" />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey add `*` in ` <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate replace to="/configuration" />} />`

Comment: the problem continues =[

Comment: I don't see what the issue is, the code appears to run as expected in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-hashrouter-basename-not-working-forked-60swc5?file=/src/App.js). I can't reproduce the error you describe.

Comment: but the code don't run, its render nothing, the console says : <Router basename="/admin"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything. 
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (created by App)
    in App

Answer (score 8):

There mostly seems to be a misunderstanding with how the `basename` prop is applied in the router, specifically the `HashRouter`. With the `HashRouter` the `basename` prop is a value that is applied against the paths the app is handling, not against the domain path where the app is served/running.

Example:

```
<HashRouter basename="/admin">
  <Link to="/dashboard" className="link"> // renders <a href="#/admin/dashboard">
    Dashboard
  </Link>
  ...
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/configuration">
      <Route path="configure" element={<Configuration />} />
      <Route index element={<SummaryPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="/appointments" element={<Appointments />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/configuration" />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

In other words, the `basename` prop value is applied to the URL ***hash*** and ***not*** the URL path, i.e. it's applied to everything *after* the hash.

```
mysite.com/someSubdomain/#/admin   /something / ... more nested paths
|--domain-|--subdomain--|#|--------------hash-----------------|
|         |             | |basename| app path | ... app subpaths
```

If you are wanting the `"/admin"` to show up prior to the hash, then this is part of where the entire app is deployed to and served up from. In this case the app needs to be deployed to `mysite.com` in a `"/admin"` subdirectory. You also won't need to specify the `basename="/admin"` if you don't want an additional `"/admin"` to show up in the app's routing.

```
mysite.com/admin/#/something
```

...

```
<HashRouter>
  <Link to="/dashboard" className="link"> // renders <a href="#/dashboard">
    Dashboard
  </Link>
  ...
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/configuration">
      <Route path="configure" element={<Configuration />} />
      <Route index element={<SummaryPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="/appointments" element={<Appointments />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/configuration" />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

update: Not a solution =[ basename not works in Routes, and hashrouter not working with basename

Some solution here:

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7128#issuecomment-582591472

but i don't know if it's the best one.

```
// url where new router is created: https://my-site/who/users
const RootModule = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes basename="who/users">
          <nav>
            <Link to="">Home</Link>
            <Link to="who/users/about">About</Link>
            <Link to="who/users/users">Users</Link>
          </nav>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="who/users/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="who/users/users" element={<Users />} />
          </Routes>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </main>
  );
};
```

and here working

<kbd>[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/hashrouterv6basename-t7r45x)</kbd>

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers your question/issue, that post seems terribly out of date. All the RRDv6 non-native routers have a `basename` prop, and the `Routes` component does not. Perhaps the post is referencing an older pre-release v6 version. I've forked your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-hashrouter-basename-not-working-tyix4n) and moved the `basename` prop back to the `HashRouter` and from what I can tell, it is all working as I'd expect it to. Even your original code in your post works as I'd expect.

Comment: but when we put the basename in hashrouter, the aplication don't render =[

Comment: its works only in browserouter, but i really need hashrouter

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I provided ***two*** codesandbox demos with your code rendering with a `HashRouter`. 1 with your code from the sandbox in your answer, and the other with your code from the post.

Comment: i opened your sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-hashrouter-basename-not-working-tyix4n?file=/src/App.js) but with that `code`<HashRouter basename="/admin">`code` the page dont render

Comment: this is the error in console:
<Router basename="/admin"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything. 
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (created by App)
    in App

Comment: The URL you are trying to access should be something like `https://tyix4n.csb.app/#/admin`. Try [https://tyix4n.csb.app/#/admin/](https://tyix4n.csb.app/#/admin/).

Comment: it worked with that, but i want the "admin" before the "#", in react router dom v5 my url is  https://tyix4n.csb.app/admin/#/something, but in v6 it changed i think, we cant do the old type anymore?

Comment: I don't believe anything changed between v5 and v6. Here's the v5 `HashRouter` [`basename`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter/basename-string) doc. Note that the basename value is *after* the hash. Anything before the hash is where the app is located and being served from on the server.

Comment: yes, but why that simple aplication cant render with https://tyix4n.csb.app/admin/#/anything , with BrowserRouter its render normaly =/, but HashRouter nope

Comment: from now we use mysite.com/admin and when we enter in the aplication, that occours in v5:

Comment: Because codesandbox is running the code from `"https://tyix4n.csb.app"`, not `"https://tyix4n.csb.app/admin"`. If you serve your app up from `"mysite.com/admin"` then the "admin" part will be part of the URL path and not in the hash. If you are adding another "admin" to the hash, it will also show up there.

Comment: mysite.com/admin/#/admin/something, it repeat the basename, because that we want to change to the v6

Comment: humm, makes sense, so in the sever of my company, maybe the http name is mysite.com/admin, when we enter in this page, the app will be download and use the base url from the server before the /#/, i think i can understand the issue now, its not a problem with react router dom, it's the base url from the sever

Comment: Right, I think you've got it now. To be honest I don't really see the value of specifying a `basename` prop in a `HashRouter` since the React app is already running on whatever sub-route it's being served from and all routing is relative from  "/" which is basically "." from the package.json file. It seems that all `basename="/admin"` does in a `HashRouter` is push all the app routes down a level.

Comment: yes, no need the basename if the sever url already contain that, thanks for the help, you really saved me!

Comment: Sorry it was a long, strange trip, but we eventually got there. Cheers and good luck.