# react-router-dom createHashRouter does not find any matches with basename property

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I created a simple implementation of a reactJS + RRD, following the tutorial on the react-router-dom website, and once I had a working version from their documentation, I modified the implementation for hash routing. The code looks like this in main.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import {
    createHashRouter,
    createBrowserRouter,
    RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <div>Hello world!</div>,
    }
];

const router = createHashRouter(routes, {
        basename: 'transfers'
    }
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Seems dead-simple.

I access the app from a URL of https://www.localenv.dev/react#transfers

For context, this is my package.json:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "axios": "1.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "6.11.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "storybook-addon-pseudo-states": "2.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predev": "node predev.js",
    "dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:storybook/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/react": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.14-next.2",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "0.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "6.7.3",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "0.6.12",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.0",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "storybook": "7.0.12",
    "webpack": "5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1"
  }
}
```

When accessing the page with RRD implemented I get the following console messages:

`<Router basename="/transfers"> is not able to match the URL "transfers" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything.`

What can I do to resolve this issue?

I tried modifying the value for "basename", modifying "path" to explicit URL values and catch-all ("/*" and "*") values, tested that other points of failure are not in play by using createBrowserRouter() and verified that this works when using a catch-all value for "path", and delved into the documentation (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router) for other props to pass to createHashRouter().

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72815638/react-router-dom-v6-hashrouter-basename-not-working/72821602#72821602

Comment: From what I understand of that SO answer, what you are explaining is that basename works against "hash" (i.e. `window.location.hash`). That is my expectation. So in my case the hash is "#transfers", and if I set `basename: 'transfers'` then I see the error that I mention in the post. Further, regardless of setting basename or not, if I change path from `'/'` to `'/*'` in the route I get the same error. Are you suggesting this happens because RRD imposes a hash structure like `#/transfers` instead of `#transfers`?

Comment: All router routes are assumed from root `"/"`, so if you add a `basename` prop I believe you are telling the router that all routes and links are now relative to `".../#/transfers"`. The app will need to be "bootstrapped" into the `"/transfers"` path for the rest of the app's paths and links to work, or all the route paths and link targets may need to include this "prefix".

Comment: That does not seem to be in the scope of RRD's props. I believe previous versions supported a `props.hashType` of 'slash' | 'noslash' to support my application's contract and needs. Is there some workaround?

Comment: I don't believe so, removing `hashType` was a breaking change from RRD v4/5 to v6. I see a few closed issues filed in `react-router`, this one of note: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7703, which *might* have a workaround.

Comment: I don't think there is a viable solution from that issue or any others I have researched. I appreciate you exploring this topic with me. It seems like the only path forward for me is to either adopt the hash schema of `#/transfers` to leverage RRD for navigation, or try another solution like wouter (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wouter) and implement a solution that fits the current server/frontend contract.

Comment: Ok, best of luck to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that RRD does not support configuration of the hash schema. It expects a rigid hash structure of `#/`. If the case of adding a basename prop, the structure enforced takes the form of `#/basename`. There is no workaround in RRD to use a structure like `#basename/`.

See comments for more details.